# Postgres/Mac - 'service already loaded', but 'could not connect to server'

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I'm running Homebrew-installed Postgres version 9.6.3 on my Mac (High Sierra, 10.13.3), and this morning I'm finding that Postgres is having some issues. It was working fine last night, then I put the computer to sleep... when I woke it up this morning and tried to run a Phoenix app, I got

```
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.306.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
```

Running `psql` returned

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

so it seemed that perhaps the server had stopped... however, running my alias `pg-start`, which translates to `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` returns

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.3/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: service already loaded
```

So this is confusing, because it seems that one command suggests that Postgres is not running, while the other suggests that it is.

I can't recall for sure, but I may have stopped the server before putting the computer to sleep last night, which I actually usually do not do... my `pg-stop` alias is `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

though I can't see why that would cause problems, it's the only thing that sticks out in my mind as something 'different' that I may have done.

I've tried restarting my machine, but the problem persists. I'm not terribly experienced with debugging this sort of issue, so any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I resolved it, though I'm not sure what the exact problem was. To get some more error info, I ran

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

which gave me

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 323) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

which I'd encountered before, so I kind of knew how to proceed...

Here are the steps I took to resolve this:

First, I ran

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

which returned

```
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting
My-MBP:~ me$ FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1188) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

then I ran my alias `pg-stop`

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

followed by

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

again. This time, it returned

```
server starting
My-MBP:~ me$ LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-02-07 11:10:43 EST
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

and now Postgres was running correctly - `psql` commands, etc.

However, now my alias `pg-stop` wouldn't work -

```
/Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Could not find specified service
```

I ran

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop
```

and then my `pg-stop` alias was restored. So now `pg-start` and `pg-stop` are working as they should be.

I hope that this is helpful to someone in the future, but if anyone can explain what happened here, I'd really appreciated having a deeper understanding of what went wrong.